# Disable UITabBarController animation while setting rootViewContorller

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller

I have a login screen and when user submit correct credentials i just change the root view controller of `window` to my `tabbarController`
It shows a very abrupt animation like the screen is being bigger from top to bottom. I don't need any sort of animation when i logged in. How could i stop `UITabBarController` from being animate?

Here is the method in my `AppDelegate` which i used to login.

```
func userDidLoggedIn() -> Void {
        tabBarController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("TabBarController") as! VaboTabBarController


        self.window?.rootViewController = self.tabBarController
        self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

        self.registerDeviceForPushNotification(UIApplication.sharedApplication())

    }
```

In my `LoginViewController` when credentials are accurate i just use below code to switch to `TabBarController`.
Here is the code.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.9, animations: {
                            let userDefault = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
                            let array = parseJSON["userData"] as! NSArray
                            appDelegate.userDidLoggedIn()
                        })
```

Comment: why you are doing this like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wrapped the presentation of the `tabbarController` into a `UIView.animateWithDuration` function.

And you display the tabbarcontroller with animation from the body of `func userDidLoggedIn()` function:

```
 self.window?.rootViewController = self.tabBarController
 self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

I think this is causing the weird animation. make the `appDelegate.userDidLoggedIn()` outside of the `animateWithDuration` function.